# No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'JObject' from content with media type 'text/html'. Is there a fix for this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

```
 protected async void Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

     JObject userInfo = new JObject();
     userInfo.Add("UserId", tb_username.Text);
     userInfo.Add("Password", Password.Text);
     userInfo.Add("Email", Email.Text);
     userInfo.CreateReader();
     string baseURI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebAPIURI"].ToString();
     using (var c = new HttpClient())
     {
         c.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURI);
         //c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
         c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
         c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
         HttpResponseMessage res = await c.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Account/Register", userInfo);
```

The error occurs below this comment. This line of code somehow causes a **status code 500**.

```
JObject result = await res.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>();
```

Whole code part:

```
string status = result["token"].ToString();

 if (status != "")
 {
     string userDir = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/") + "\\" + tb_username.Text;
     if (!Directory.Exists(userDir))
     {
         Directory.CreateDirectory(userDir);
     }
     HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, status);

     Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

     Response.Redirect("~/Home", false);
 }
 else
 {
      string message = "Username has been taken, please choose a different username.";
      System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
      sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
      sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
      sb.Append("alert('");
      sb.Append(message);
      sb.Append("')};");
      sb.Append("</script>");
      ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
  }
```

Is there a fix to this? Or can someone point out the error in my code? This is basically the codebehind for my registration page.

Comment: If you just do [`res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), what does the response look like?

Comment: @dbc its unable to implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.